# Are "scout" and "scout out" the same thing?

Tags: phrase-choice

The dictionary give pretty much the same definition for both:

> **scout.**
>
> b [+ object] : to explore (an area) in order to find information about
>   it
>
> *Several soldiers were sent ahead to scout the area.*

[Source.](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/scout)

> **scout out.**
>
> If you scout something out, you succeed in finding it after you have
>   been through an area searching for it.
>
> T*heir mission is simply to
>   scout out places where helicopters can land.*

[Source.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scout-out)

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: You scout an area; you scout out a thing.

Comment: You also scout *for* a thing. "They scout for a place where..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. To "scout" is to explore an area to find out what may be there.
"To scout out" is a phrasal verb, meaning to search for particular objectives.